# "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." when I attempt to unseal a field on a list

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2007

I have a few fields on a list that was created using a schema. The schema and list seem to have gotten out of sync, so when I try to change attributes for a field on the schema, those changes are not reflected on the list, unless they are additions (ie, new fields).

I have a few Sealed fields that I need to unseal. But when I attempt to set Sealed=false, either using SharePoint Manager, or using a utility I wrote, I get the error:
"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." I can't seem to find any more usable information about the error.

On my utility, this happens on the line:

```
field.Sealed = false;
```

I haven't even gotten to the point of trying to update the field before an exception is thrown. field.SchemaXml looks fine too. I don't see anything wrong with it.

This is happening on multiple fields in this list.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the exact error I've seen previously but from experience, you must unseal a field and call Update() before you change any other properties.

Comment: I'm not trying to change anything. Literally the only operations I do on the field is to get it, and then attempt to unseal it, at which point the exception is thrown. I've tried allowunsafeupdates just for gits and shiggles with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error and what is the field that is failing?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.sealed.aspx), you cannot change out of the box or external data fields:

- InvalidOperationException: An attempt is made to assign a value to a field type that is built into SharePoint. The true/false value of such fields must remain at its factory setting.
- NotSupportedException: An attempt is made to assign false when the SharePoint field is an external data column.

Update (to highlight information that might be hidden in the comments):

Call [SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.contains.aspx) to avoid (or detect) InvalidOperationException. The Sealed property cannot be set if SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains returns true.

Comment: It's InvalidOperationException and it's on the Sealed property. This is something you can toggle to keep field settings from being deleted or modified in any meaningful way through the UI.

Comment: Sorry, not what property, but what field? What is the name or GUID of the field that you are trying to change the Sealed property on? Based on the error, it sounds like it is an OOTB field and cannot be modified.

Comment: This is an old coworker of mine and we're going back and forth in email at the same time - which is why I'm answering. It's a Note field. The only difference from other sealed fields is this was sealed per an XML definition rather than through OM code. Now he's trying to unseal using code. I'm wondering if that's the issue here - that it was originally sealed through XML.

Comment: <Field 
                Type=\"Note\" 
                ID=\"{blah blah blah}\" 
                Name=\"Description\" 
                RichText=\"TRUE\" 
                DisplayName=\"Description\" 
                Sortable=\"FALSE\" 
                Sealed=\"TRUE\" 
                SourceID=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3\" 
                StaticName=\"Description\" 
                ColName=\"ntext2\" />

Comment: That's the SchemaXML. Also, it has happened on more than just this one field. It happens in SharePoint Manager. It happens on a couple of dates, but not another date. It happens on a choice column. 

I made the mistake of sealing these fields to prevent users from mucking with them. I did this a while ago, when I knew less about SharePoint than I do now. It seemed like a good idea at the time.

The fields were sealed in the schema definition, not in code.

Comment: Also, to be thorough, I just ran it against another three other text fields and two date fields. 

I then found a field that DOESN'T have this problem, sealed it with SPM, and then unsealed it with my utility. So it must be something unique to these fields. It's not the entire list that is broken ... just the handful of fields that I want to unseal.

Comment: To quote Seinfeld, "you yadda yadda-ed over the best part." Try this, call SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains("{blah blah blah}") where "blah blah blah" is the actual Guid of your field. You cannot update the Sealed property if SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains returns true.

Comment: And it does contain true.

So how did I get into this mess? This was a field declared in my schema. Why is in this bizarre state? It wasn't sealed when it was created. That came later. I sealed it like two versions ago in the schema. 

I don't understand why it is now in an unchangeable state.

Comment: Ok, I think I have it all figured out. You're right .. these guids do show up in fieldswss.xml. That explains what's going on. I don't know why the previous developer used builtin fields instead of just defining new fields. 

I think I have multiple problems here, since we still weren't able to unseal one of the fields I created on Production, and it threw the same error. But I think that's a separate issue that I'll have to research.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If this has been helpful, please upvote (the up arrow) and/or accept this answer (the checkmark). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Rich's answer, if you need to modify a column that is in the SPBuiltInFieldId collection, you can set the GUID of the column to new GUID() during runtime then make any changes to the column you need. Be careful, there is a reason that Microsoft attempts to lock you out of editing these columns. I needed to fix the list relationship for the Resources (Facilities) column in my group calendar and this allowed me to do so.